# Providing a mechanism for end users to install Silverlight 2.0 without going to the Microsoft site

Tags: silverlight-2.0

Our web-based application is installed at end-customers. Typically these customers do not have access to the internet. Part of the next version of our application is Silverlight 2.0 based.

When a browser without the Silverlight 2.0 plugin tries to access our the Silverlight portion of our app, the customer gets the standard "Install Microsoft Silverlight" image which, when clicked on, tries to go to the Microsoft download site.

Is there a way that we can control this page? We would like to provide the Silverlight plugin with our app so a user could then directly download it from our app when they don't already have the plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript API which was originally available in v1 of Silverlight to edit things like the loading animation and also the Install mechanism.
[Silverlight Javascript API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903928(VS.95).aspx)